# Creating structure on the surface of a sphere

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, vertices, edges

I currently started working with Unity and require a few 3d models for my game idea. I want to use Blender for this and have so far up to zero experience with it.

I have a sperical planet as the game environenment and I want to build streets, bridges etc. on it. I want these structures to be 3-dimensional, that means the streets are a little bit raised up compared to the rest of the sphere's surface. Same goes for the bridges. How would I do that.
I understand the concepts of the Blender's vertices, edges, triangles and quads, but I think the best approach would be to make extra model for the structures that have the spheres "curve" so they can be put on the sphere wihtout having odd geometry instead on working directly with the sphere's geometry. This would also make it easier to mix the different models.
I thought of building straigt part of the street by creating a "ring" and make its radius bigger than the one of the sphere and cut out pieces. But for a curved street this approach does not work that easily.

Do you have any advice or guide on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Small Planet Effect" ? Where a skyscraper starts small at the bottom and gets larger at the top. The top then being curved.

Comment: Yes, something like that except my geometry is not that tall. Imagine the planet with a radius of "50 meters" and the street is only lifted up by "1 meter".

Comment: ok, create a Sphere and create a building. Select the bottom most vertices of the building and add them to Vertex Group. Now add a Shrinkwrap modifier and select the target as the Sphere and select the Vertex Group. Rinse and repeat for all buildings/features. The bottom parts, as defined by the vertex groups will be "sucked" to the surface of the sphere.

Comment: Thank you, that is how I thought I could do it but I did not know the steps. Does this also work for street making a left/right turn? Following your guide I could simply create the single street elements and then simply get them sucked onto the sphere's surface.

Comment: yep, any mesh will work.Even something flat like a road.